# Set Default MS Excel Zoom to 125% on Mac

Tags: ms-office, zoom

For some reason, Excel text is teeny tiny on this Mac.

How do I set it to ALWAYS zoom at 125%?

Do I have to save a default template or something at 125%, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Version of Office? Precise Mac, display & OS? Help us to help you.

Comment: MacBook Pro 2022 M2 -- Ventura 13.2.1 -- using a 20 inch Acer monitor (either one).

Comment: Excel v16.7 --- hm -- seems the functionality is limited on Mac. I might try saving a new default template at the 125% zoom and figure out how to get that template to launch at start. Big pain in the butt though.

Comment: With Excel 16.73, Excel remembers the zoom setting for each workbook from the previous time I opened the workbook.  New workbooks are always 100%.  Good enough for me.  You can create a template with bigger zoom and use that for new documents.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276016/change-the-default-zoom-level-for-new-documents-in-excel-2016-for-mac

Comment: There is no simple solution. @Gilby has provided the link to a workaround for new documents. For existing documents, the workaround could be to place a macro in a macro-enabled Excel file, assign a shortcut to the macro and have the Excel file automatically opened at start-up as hidden. Then you can just run that macro manually after you open an Excel file. The advantage of that macro to the regular zoom menu option would be that it can be written such that it could set the zoom level for all worksheets in an Excel file, new or otherwise, without having to select the worksheets manually.

Comment: Ugh. A huge operation to make Excel simply readable. I'm not an old-timer either; it's just teeny text. Oof.